# getGroupView set item similar like Simple_Expandable_List_item in Android project

Tags: java, android

I am working on Android project. Now I have to create my own expandable list. This is the solution I follow:

[link to source code of expandable list that I am working on](http://www.allappsdevelopers.com/TopicDetail.aspx?TopicID=c991d70a-4570-4e4b-8378-2191a4247a84)

And that's the code which generate me TextView (it's element from the list). I would like to create instead of this TextView something like android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item item. I mean to put some Image on the left, and then text. How I can do that?

I've tried with Button and setting left icon on Button, but it didn't help. Button won't expand / collapse my list.

```
 @Override
              public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                           View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                     TextView tv = new TextView(Vincent_ThreeelevellistActivity.this);
                     tv.setText("->FirstLevel");
                     tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                     tv.setTextSize(20);
                     tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                     tv.setPadding(10, 7, 7, 7);
                     return tv;

              }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use like this. This code is only an example. Please do not change the parameters and implement your code accordingly.

```
@Override
       public View getGroupView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {   

       ViewHolder holder = null;
       TextView title = null;
       TextView detail = null;
       ImageView i11=null;
       RowData rowData= getItem(position);
       if(null == convertView){
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
 }
             holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
             title = holder.gettitle();
             itle.setText(rowData.mTitle);
             detail = holder.getdetail();
             detail.setText(rowData.mDetail);                                                     

             i11=holder.getImage();
             i11.setImageResource(imgid[rowData.mId]);
             return convertView;
}
            private class ViewHolder {
            private View mRow;
            private TextView title = null;
            private TextView detail = null;
            private ImageView i11=null; 

            public ViewHolder(View row) {
            mRow = row;
 }
         public TextView gettitle() {
             if(null == title){
                 title = (TextView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.title);
                }
            return title;
         }     

         public TextView getdetail() {
             if(null == detail){
                  detail = (TextView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.detail);
                    }
           return detail;
         }
        public ImageView getImage() {
             if(null == i11){
                  i11 = (ImageView) mRow.findViewById(R.id.img);
                                      }
                return i11;
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not that clear. However from what i understood here's my solution.

Option1 : You can create a custom layout in xml and then inflate it and return from the getGroupView.

Option2 : You can set a compoundDrawable for your textview item so that it will display an image next to it.

If you want to customize the Down arrow mark you can set the android:groupIndicator for the expandable listview.